# How to make extended class not fire method from above class if method names are the same?

Tags: java, extends

I am having problem with two classes in my program that are having same method and one of them is extending another.

Class `A`:

```
class A{

  public A(){
    this.sameMethod();
  }

  public void sameMethod(){
    System.out.println("This is A");
  }
}
```

Class `B` that extends class `A`:

```
class B extends A{

  private int i;

  public B(int i){
    this.i = i;
    this.sameMethod();
  }

  public void sameMethod(){
    System.out.println("This is B");
    System.out.println("int value: " + i);
  }
}
```

Class `C` that extends class `B`:

```
class C extends B{

  public C(int i){
    super(i);
  }
}
```

And when I initialize class `C` with parameter `int i = 1`, then I get this output:

```
This is B
int value: null
This is B
int value: 1
```

Why class `A` is calling for `sameMethod()` from class `B`? 
How to solve this problem without changing method name?

How to get this output?:

```
This is A
This is B
int value: 1
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: This is A,
This is B
int value: 1

Comment: The `sameMethod` in `B` overrides the one defined in `A`. If you don't want it to override, perhaps you should give your methods different names.

Comment: "Why class A is calling for sameMethod() from class B?" - because `B.sameMethod()` overrides `A.sameMethod()` - admittedly without explicitly doing so using `@Override`, and it would be better to use that annotation. But this is entirely normal and intentional behavior for virtual method dispatch.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: `super();` in `B`'s constructor wouldn't compile

Comment: Is it possible to keep name of this methods same and get output like I posted in question or I must change method names?

Comment: You could make the methods private, as long as you only want to call them from within the class that defines them. Private methods are not subject to overriding.

Comment: I have removed `super();` from class B from example code in question. Now it should compile.

Comment: @Albert451 No, it still won't compile as is, because your methods have no return type. Ideally you should check code compiles and does what you describe before you post it.

Comment: Also nowhere in your code is `i` set. How does it get the value 1 in the output? Please be sure to post *exactly* the code you are using.

Comment: Now it should. I am sorry about that.

Comment: No, it still won't compile. Please try and compile your code yourself instead of posting here for people to tell you whether or not it compiles.

Comment: Now it compiles. How to make class `A` call `public void sameMethod()` from its own class instead of `public void sameMethod()` from class `B`?

Comment: I still don't see how `i` gets its value. The output cannot be from the code you posted.

Comment: I did not save edit. This is an code that compiles.

Comment: Where does this output line `int value: null` come from?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent `B.sameMethod` from overriding `A.sameMethod` (while keeping the same name), then you can simply make the methods private:

```
class A {

    public A(int i) {
        this.sameMethod();
    }

    private void sameMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is A");
    }
}
```

And the same thing in `B`:

```
class B extends A {

    private int i;

    public B(int i) {
        super(i);
        this.sameMethod();
    }

    private void sameMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is B");
        System.out.println("int value: " + i);
    }
}
```

This way `A.sameMethod` is not inherited by `B` and the behavior will be as you expect.

Comment: What if I want to make them public? In this situation it is not possible to make this methods have same name?

Comment: This won't work correctly either because `this.sameMethod()` is called twice.

Comment: @Albert451 You can't achieve that if `A.sameMethod` is accessible to `B` (and that's not just public, it could also be package scope or protected)

Comment: @Albert451 All public instance methods in Java are virtual. You can't have a different method called based on reference type of the object's variable.

Comment: @Jai Would you mind elaborating? I think that's the idea in the question: to call `A.samemethod` and `B.sameMethod` in isolation.

Comment: What if I will make `sameMethod();` protected? Will it work?

Comment: @ernest_k this is exactly what I want to achieve. Please, look at part in question where I typed what output do I expect. Is it possible?

Comment: @Albert451 As I noted in previous comment: if the method is accessible to `B`, then it will be inherited and overridden. So the method has to be private.

Comment: My bad, this works.... but why not just make `sameMethod()` call `super.sameMethod()` in `B`? Making constructors call the same method at different inheritance level sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @Jai It's surely a bad idea, if the methods are meant to be unrelated, then they should have different names to start off with. And after that, as you say, the overridden method should just call the super implementation.

Comment: @Jai why does it sound like a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) concept called inheritance. The parent class defines a particular behavior, and the child class can change how it behaves. When you define a method with the same signature in a child class, the child class is said to have *overridden* the behavior defined by its parent class.

When you call `this.sameMethod()` in the parent class `A`, it will call the `sameMethod()` defined in `B` because the method has already been `redefined`.

In your case, it looks like you need your child class to do something *additional* on top of what its parent has done.

```
class A{

  public A(){
    this.sameMethod();
  }

  public void sameMethod(){
    System.out.println("This is A");
  }
}

class B extends A{

  private int i;

  public B(int i){
    // Parent class has already called this, you don't do this here
    // this.sameMethod();

    this.i = i; // You really need this
  }

  public void sameMethod(){
    super.sameMethod(); // This means that the child class also does whatever its parent does
    System.out.println("This is B");
    System.out.println("int value: " + i);
  }
}
```

I would say that calling `sameMethod()` at constructors in different levels is *generally* a bad idea. If the base class (or parent class) calls a particular method in its constructor, there is an implicit agreement that all instances needs to do something *once* to initialize something. Knowing that your parent already does that and you are also trying to do something *similar* is likely to cause confusion when someone else looks at your code. If it has to do something extra, it is definitely more clear to have another method, which the subclass can call in its constructor as well.

An example:

```
class Diner {
    public Diner() {
        this.eatWithMouth();
    }
    public void eatWithMouth() {
        System.out.println("Ate something.");
    }
}

class ThirstyDiner extends Diner {
    public ThirstyDiner() {
        super();
        this.drinkWater();
    }
    public void drinkWater() {
        System.out.println("Drank something.");
    }
}

class ThirstyDiner extends Diner {
    public ThirstyDiner() {
        super();
        this.eatWithMouth();
    }
    public void eatWithMouth() {
        System.out.println("Drank something."); // You don't actually eat anything -> contract violation
    }
}

class SlowDiner extends Diner {
    public SlowDiner () {
        super();
    }
    public void eatWithMouth() {
        super.eatWithMouth();
        System.out.println("Took 10 hours."); // At least this is marginally related
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but in my case I want to keep first class that does not extend anything to use its own `sameMethod()` instead of overwritten `sameMethod()` from class `B`. Does your answer mean that class `A` does not have orginal content of this method anymore because it is overwritten?

Comment: @Albert451 When you extends from a base class, the overridden method only overrides when you have an instance of the extended class. This means that `new A().sameMethod()` will do what you have defined in `A` while `new B().sameMethod()` will do the overridden implementation in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with your example is that you call an overridable method from a constructor of a non-final class. This leads to exactly the problems you show.

Sequence of operations:

- new C(1);
- enter C(int)
- super(1);
- enter B(int)
- super();
- initialize instance variables of class A
- enter A()
- sameMethod(); => because of dynamic binding calls B.sameMethod();
- enter B.sameMethod()
- access uninitialized B.i (with default value of 0; at least that should be 0)
- leave B.sameMethod()
- leave A()
- initialize instance variables of class B
- assign B.i
- ...

As you see, the call to sameMethod() in A() is a really bad idea.
Normally, you should only call private or final methods from a constructor.